# different encrypted text is generated by same AES algorithm?

Tags: c, encryption, aes

i am implementing AES algorithm in c from [aes encryption program](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/35340-c-aes-implementation/)
and also we write AES program in java , the problem occur in generation of encrypted data both are different .
input text : 358960040119672
key : mlabs

output :
 1. by java(android):"vcpBspcYHtjlMgbQJI3aWg==" 
 2. by c :"`Äç © õ#«0Z"÷›ý"

why this special char. are shown in c . how to deal with this ??

Comment: What this question has to do with Android?

Comment: if i send encrypted data generated by c code to java(android) to decrypt then there is problem in decrypt due to it's special char.

Comment: There are a lot of unanswered questions here, besides the obvious base64 difference. What key generation algorithm is being used? ("mlabs" can't be the actual key because it's not long enough. Passwords/passphrases are generally hashed to produce the actual key.) Are both sides using ECB?

Comment: downvoting for refusal to post code.

Comment: sorry i hold this task and see for DES .

Comment: actually the encrypted string generated by android is using the base64 encoding whereas on my side i.e c code not encoding into base64 that why the string mismatch . encrypted string generated by c code are encoded into base64 so that it contain ascii character which match the final string with generating by android source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java output has been encoded with the Base64 algorithm after encryption, and the C has not.

Comment: now i am convert the encrypted output from c into base64(Base64Encode()) but still they are not same.

Comment: @user1196792: That output is not even a full AES block size, so you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably whith padding and conversion. Turn data into bytes, (hex for instance) because result of 128bit encryption is 18 octets of any value (even unprintable ASCII characters). Make sure, that both sided use same padding.

AES 128 bit is defined as CHIPERTEXT[16 octets] = AES(KEY[16 octets], PLAIN[16 octets])) and there is no convention to use strings.